# How to remove annoying vertical whitespace that is blocking width to fit-to-screen?

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

I have a Django-Dash-Plotly app, I'm trying to solve the issue I have where there is a slither of white on the right of the screen. Look at the picture below, notice small but extra amount of white space that is causing my responsive layout to allow for extra width scrolling (I want my app to fit-to-screen).

Are there any HTML or CSS properties that unknowingly add this white space?

[image]

Here is my Dash Layout and HTML meta-tags

```
app = DjangoDash('StockBuckets', add_bootstrap_links=True, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX], suppress_callback_exceptions = True,  meta_tags=[
        {"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.2, minimum-scale=0.5"}])



body = html.Div(
    [dbc.Jumbotron(
    [
        dbc.Container(dcc.Dropdown(id="dynamic-dropdown", options=options, multi=True, placeholder="Enter Symbols of Interest"),
 
        fluid=True
        )

    ], 
     style = {'background-color': '#68d984'}, fluid=True,
)
   
    , dbc.Row(dbc.Col(html.Div([  
                                   ],id='output-graph'),lg=8, md=11, xs=12),justify="center")


    , html.Div(style={"width":"100%", "height":'25px'})


    , dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col(children=[  
                                ],id='quickfacts',lg=4, md=11, xs=12)

          , dbc.Col(children=[
                                ], id='returnrates',lg=7, md=11, xs=12)
                                                                        ], justify="center", align="center")
    , html.Div(style={"width":"100%", "height":'25px'})

     , dbc.Row(dbc.Col(children=[
                                ], id='advancedstats', lg=11, md=11, xs=12), justify="center",  align="center")


    , html.Div(style={"width":"100%", "height":'25px'})


    , dbc.Row([dbc.Col(children=[
                                ],id= 'nextreport',lg=4, md=4, xs=12)

           , dbc.Col(children=[
                                ],id='nextdividend',lg=4, md=4, xs=12)
            ], justify="center"),
       ])
```

my index.html file for Django

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
  {% load plotly_dash %}
  {% plotly_header %}

  </head>


  <body>
  {% block page_content %}
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <h1 class="mt-5">Compare Equities in the SP500</h1>
          <p class="lead">Invest smarter, use data to your advantage <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-lightning" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M11.251.068a.5.5 0 0 1 .227.58L9.677 6.5H13a.5.5 0 0 1 .364.843l-8 8.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.842-.49L6.323 9.5H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.364-.843l8-8.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .615-.09zM4.157 8.5H7a.5.5 0 0 1 .478.647L6.11 13.59l5.732-6.09H9a.5.5 0 0 1-.478-.647L9.89 2.41 4.157 8.5z"/>
  </svg> </p>
          <!--<ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li> <span class="badge badge-primary">New</span> features coming soon.</li>
          </ul> -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    

      
        {% plotly_direct name='StockBuckets' %} 
      
  </body>
     {% plotly_footer %}
  {% endblock %}

</html>
```

Because I'm using Dash, the HTML and CSS code is a bit spread out. To make it easier here are some other CSS styles that I'm using `margin-top`, `margin-left`, `padding`, `width`.

Would greatly appreciate on how to get rid of this annoyance! Thank you.

EDIT:

Found the issue being two div elements:
[image]

Notice the 405px for width? When the device screen im using is 375px. This is the same for the next div below this one. I'm playing around with padding and screen size But i have no clue why these two `html.Div()` have extra width...

Comment: I suspect it is caused due to one of your child element having more width than parent. Try checking one element at a time in Inspector mode, so you can find out which has more width, padding etc.
Provide a working example or reproducible code, so can be more specific about the issue.

Comment: @AmarenderReddy Thank you for your comment. I'm currently inspecting the elements using Google Chrome dev tools, I wish I could provide some reproducible code to help.

Comment: So I can see some of the `html.Div()` have a larger width than the screen. Would you know why that would happen automatically?

Comment: You should be on the right track using Inspect. A quick tip is do press **Del** on some root element. You can press **Ctrl+Z** to undo. But for me, I just try deleting everything until I see the change I want, then you slowly close in to children elements and you'll eventually find the culprit. Sometimes, it's not one element causing the trouble, but it can be an interaction of multiple elements.

Comment: I found the culprit, there are two of them. Please see my OG post, maybe you know why two div elements both have an extra width of 30 more pixels...

Answer (score 1):

Its because of min-width specified somewhere. Target the element which has 405px width and add min-width: unset;

Comment: So I made those edits, nothing has changed. Sad face.

Comment: Are you using any library like bootstrap. If so, use min-width: unset !important;

Comment: Yes I'm using bootstrap,  I thought I fixed it by changing the size of smaller screens (in bootstrap styles) from 12 to 11. But I was actually wrong. I did not manage to fix it.

Comment: Okay, I just solved it by adding `style = {'width': '100vw'}` to every bootstrap component in my Dash app.

Comment: I would suggest not to specify width: 100vw to every element. Just specify the required width to parent and add width: 100% to the child components. If you did so, ignore my comment.